# Calculating running total

Tags: python, loops, pandas, count, cumulative-sum

I have data frame df and I would like to keep a running total of names that occur in a column of that data frame. I am trying to calculate the running total column:

```
    name    running total
    a            1
    a            2 
    b            1 
    a            3
    c            1
    b            2
```

There are two ways I thought to do this:

1. Loop through the dataframe and use a separate dictionary containing name and current count. The current count for the relevant name would increase by 1 each time the loop is carried out, and that value would be copied into my dataframe.
2. Change the count in field for each value in the dataframe. In excel I would use a countif combined with a drag down formula A$1:A1 to fix the first value but make the second value relative so that the range I am looking in changes with the row.

The problem is I am not sure how to implement these. Does anyone have any ideas on which is preferable and how these could be implemented?

Comment: if you're using pandas check out the [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@bunji is right. I'm assuming you're using pandas and that your data is in a dataframe called `df`. To add the running totals to your dataframe, you could do something like this:

`df['running total'] = df.groupby(['name']).cumcount() + 1`

The `+ 1` gives you a 1 for your first occurrence instead of 0, which is what you would get otherwise.

Comment: So simple! Thanks